# parseJSON issue

Tags: jquery

The following code is coming back as `Invalid Character`, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is what the JSON looks like after it has been parsed... :)

```
 { "AccountNumber": "069211424", "FirstName": "anthony", "Surname":         "Smith", "Postcode": "pe112hs" }
```

Thanks for the response guys, i was in a rush as had only 4 minutes to leave the building,  I shall post the actual code tommorow for you at work and you will see what i am getting at.

I dont use the parseJSON function, jquery is complaining about it, i am using a simple ajax call to httphandler in a control i have built.

I can run the code on a test page on a test site and it runs fine, happy days. when the code is plugged into the main application I get this bizzare error. I have validated the JSON and its fine, yes indeed the JSON is parsed I realize my mistake in my original question....

The peice of JSON it is complaining about is similar to this ...

```
data: { 
       AccountNumber: this.AccountNumber, 
       Forename: this.Forename,
       Surname: this.Surname,
       Postcode: this.Postcode
     }
```

It has been a long day :(

I shall post the full ajax call tommorow,  Regards all ...

Ps, before anyone asks, yes as you can see only valid characters are being passed in to the hashtable ...

Comment: Its valid on JSON lint, but invalid when I hit a break point in Visual studio 2012 and check my JS

Comment: You are not parsing a JSON string. You are passing an object literal into `parseJSON`, which is converted to the string `[object Object]`. The JSON parser ties to read this as an array (since it starts with `[`), but trips on the `o` in `object`.

Comment: Yep. It's already parsed.

Answer (score 3):

You are not parsing a JSON string. You are defining an object literal and passing it into `parseJSON`. You don't need to parse this object -- it's *already* an object. Just use the object.

Here's why you get an error: when the JSON parser gets an argument, it converts it to a string. The object here is converted to the string `[object Object]`. The JSON parser ties to read this string as an array (since it starts with `[`), but trips on the `o` in `object` when it expects a number, quotation mark, or nested JSON object/array.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get a response from this function you would need to pass JSON string. This means that you would need a quote around the string.

```
$.parseJSON('{ "AccountNumber": "0692424", "FirstName": "anthony", "Surname": "Smith-Brewster", "Postcode": "pe112hp" }')
```

Answer (score 0):

try to parse a string object... not an object.

```
$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify({"AccountNumber":"0692424","FirstName":"anthony","Surname":"Smith-Brewster","Postcode":"pe112hp"}))
```

Comment: this way he can see it's not a parseJSON malfunction

Comment: Absolutely mental... and not very helpful.#

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response guys, i see my error here,  I shall post the atcul code tommorow for you at work and you will see what i am getting at.

I dont use the parseJSON function, jquery is complaining about it, i am using a simple ajax call to httphandler in a control i have built.

I can run the code on a test page on a test site and it runs fine, happy days. when the code is plugged into the main application I get this bizzare error. I have validated the JSON and its fine, yes indeed the JSON is parsed I realize my mistake in the question.

The peice of JSON it is complaining about is similar to this ...

```
data: { 
       AccountNumber: this.AccountNumber, 
       Forename: this.Forename,
       Surname: this.Surname,
       Postcode: this.Postcode
     }
```

It has been a long day :(

I shall post the full ajax call tommorow,  Regards all ...

Ps, before anyone asks, yes only valid characters are being passed in to the hashtable ...